# I need to install ethernet driver during arch install

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, system-installation, ethernet

I've been trying to set up a dual boot with Windows 10 and Arch Linux. I started off by dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu just to get a feel for everything. When I did that I had to install ethernet drivers to just be able to connect to the internet. So now that I know how to install Ubuntu I thought it would be time to try out Arch. So, I start up the live CD and I don't have any internet like I thought would happen. So I try to install the drivers from a usd stick when I get an error saying "make: command not found". I haven't the slightest idea of how to get around this, and I can't really move on with the installation until it's fixed. Any ideas of how to do that?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a network adapter that is supported by the kernel. Either an ethernet or WiFi would do and USB ones are available for next to nothing.  Once you've got your Arch installed, you can install `make` and all the other tools you'll need to compile a driver for your main ethernet adapter.

Comment: When you are in the Arch Linux Live CD, what is the output of `ifconfig -a`?